# Solve PermGen errors when building in IntelliJ with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, intellij-idea, gigaspaces

If I get PermGen OutOfMemoryError from the app server when building my project in IntelliJ with Maven, is it the heap that Maven uses that I should increase? I use Win7, 8GB RAM and I get PermGen from the appserver when I rebuild the project with maven.

Comment: What do you mean you get PermGen from the appserver? What does maven do in this build? Normally it just compiles and creates a jar or a war or an ear. How is it using "the appserver" in this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[image]

add vm opt to mvn `-XX:MaxPermSize=128M`

Comment: Thank you. Solved my issue running Jetty with Maven plugin on Mac.

Comment: Thanks, never had this issue on Windows or Ubuntu, on a Mac was the only thing that made it work. You're  a dev hero! =) ( Although 128m was too little to my mvn tomcat7:run)